# Is there a well-known or effective algorithm for cover problem with allowed overlaps?

Tags: algorithm, set

It is known that Knuth's Algorithm X or Dancing Links is used to resolve exact cover problem. But now I have a problem similar with exact cover.

The problem has some overlapped area, different from exact cover. In exact cover, all coverage’s height/weight is 1. But in my problem, the coverage may has different heights (always a positive integer less than 4).

For example, I just want to find the subsets from a gave sets to cover with S [ 2, 1, 3]:
Now, A [1,0,2] and B [1,1,1] are the expected subsets.

```
  S = [2, 1, 3]
  A = [1, 0, 2]
  B = [1, 1, 1]
  C = [0, 1, 0]
  D = [1, 1, 0]
```

Any clue or pager, thank you very much~

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what condition the solution must satisfy? The example makes it look like a linear combination, if the weights don't need to be integral then it's a linear algebra problem

Comment: Sure, thanks. The height mentioned above is always a positive integer.

Comment: Since in your case the numbers are not too big, you can still encode your problem in an exact cover problem by duplicating the columns.

Comment: @hivert thanks for your advisement. It sounds very useful, I'll try it.